# Bad emails about you to your current employer

Tags: employer-relations

What will new employer do if they receive bad (maybe anonymous) email about you (perhaps from your ex employer)? What can you do ?

Comment: This isn't answerable.  An email from a previous employer saying "Tomas was let go because he was embezzling money from the company, here's a link to a news report discussing the arrest" is going to be rather different from an anonymous email saying "Tomas is a pain to work with".

Comment: Can you give more context? This is a very general question. It would help to know the specifics. Generally there's no reason this should ever happen. But there's a difference between "This Employee set the building on fire" and "This Employee is temperamental."

Comment: What they will do depends on the employer, who receives the email, and what the email says, doesn't it? How can we know what they will do? Until they actually do something, how can we say what should be done about it?

Comment: I changed my job to another company with better working environment, my old employer was not happy when I lefl  and I just worked there for 2.5 months.

Comment: How did you become aware of the bad-mouthing? Did your current employer mention it, or perhaps a former colleague? Have you seen the email yourself? Are you certain it comes from your old boss? I can keep doing the third degree but I suggest you write those details in the body of the question, as it is not answerable without them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, I don't see the context where they can do anything.

(Speaking from the U.S. standpoint) Employers are very restricted in the types of information they can exchange with other employers about employees.

If the email is anonymous, then the source cannot be verified and the information cannot be considered reliable. They can't do anything with it.

If the email is not anonymous and can be traced back to the former employer, you can sue the pants off of your former employer and if your new employer acts on the information, you can sue the pants off of them too.

That said, if the experience puts a really bad taste in their mouth, it will probably put strain on your employment, and they will quickly be able to create a different unrelated circumstance that puts your employment at risk.

You should provide more context and detail.